# Multiple graphs sharing same X-axis, and group of yaxis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to draw a graph like attached in the image [Sample Graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Lev.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


data_set=  [
{'date':'2018-05-20','server':'server1','api':'api1','count':4},
{'date':'2018-05-21','server':'server1','api':'api1','count':6},
{'date':'2018-05-22','server':'server1','api':'api1','count':10},
{'date':'2018-05-23','server':'server1','api':'api1','count':10},
{'date':'2018-05-24','server':'server1','api':'api1','count':14},

{'date':'2018-05-20','server':'server1','api':'api2','count':20},
{'date':'2018-05-21','server':'server1','api':'api2','count':22},
{'date':'2018-05-22','server':'server1','api':'api2','count':20},
{'date':'2018-05-23','server':'server1','api':'api2','count':23},
{'date':'2018-05-24','server':'server1','api':'api2','count':20},
{'date':'2018-05-24','server':'server2','api':'api1','count':30},
{'date':'2018-05-21','server':'server2','api':'api2','count':20}]

f, (axs) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_set)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df = df.set_index('date')

grouped = df.groupby(['api'])

for (name, df1), ax in zip(grouped, axs.flat):
     df1.plot(y='count', ax=ax)


plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1, 0.25, -0.2), bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
```

I am not getting the results I want, Can some one please guide me?

This is the graph I am getting now. [Currently getting this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGlKZ.png)

[Image from group by Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzeoC.png)

Comment: Like [one of these](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)?

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: If you adapted one of those examples to your needs, you should post that solution as an answer ... [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I was able to plot the graphs in two different subplots, for some reason I am still not getting the right graph, even though the groups were formed right.  Can some one pleas suggest what I am missing. I have posted my updated code ..

Comment: What does it mean "not getting the results I want".  What should be different?

Comment: I get this graph, please see attached graph. but, I actually need count of api(s) per server ( Ex. In first subplot I want count for both api1 & api2 for "Server1",  In the middle subplot  I want count of both api1 &apis2 for "Server2" and so on..)

Comment: What happens if you group by server instead of api?

Comment: Same thing,  I have attached the image for group by server.

Comment: If I grouped by server the apis are plotting together in the same line per server